# What are the default observers of checkout_cart_product_add_after?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am new to Magento.

I am modifying the prices in `reloadPrice()` method of `options.phtml`.
But they do not reflect in the cart after "Add to Cart"

I looked around and learnt that I need to observe the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event and do the price modifications there to get the correct prices in the cart.

However, in my code base I was not able to find any observer to `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. Also the functions from where `checkout_cart_product_add_after` is fired(in class `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart`) doesn't seem to be called.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `price.phtml` there is a lot to help you out. Almost everything related to price is there.

Comment: Yup I did my modifications in the price.phtml, js functions etc, so that reloadPrice() correctly updates the price of the product. Now the price is correctly calculated and shown in the Product's page (Product Custom options page).The problem arises when i click the "Add To Cart" button. This updated price does not load up in the "Shopping Cart" page

Comment: There is a life saver hint in magento. go to configuration-> developer and from the top left corner switch your store to default and now from debug tab activate template and blocks hints both, and now go to frontend and that would show you where to look to change something in the frontend.